# fetch data using regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to fetch data using regex

```
logdata='146.204.224.152 - feest6811 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700] "POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1" 302 4622\n197.109.77.178 - kertzmann3129 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700] "DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0" 203 26554'
pattern="""(?P<host>.*)( - \ )(?P<user_name>\w*)"""
for item in re.finditer(pattern,logdata,re.VERBOSE):
    print(item.groupdict())
```

The output looks like

```
{'host': '146.204.224.152 ', 'user_name': 'feest6811'}
{'host': '197.109.77.178 ', 'user_name': 'kertzmann3129'}
```

But I want

```
{'host': '146.204.224.152', 'user_name': 'feest6811', 'time': '21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700', 'request': 'POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1'}
{'host': '197.109.77.178', 'user_name': 'kertzmann3129', 'time': '21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700', 'request': 'DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0'}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be easier to change the log format for better parsing ?  or create a seperate log file for that. Also you should NOT!!! post public IP Adresses, you can get sued from the perons because you violate the DSGVO.

Comment: no i need to define a pattern for that

Comment: Regex101 is invaluable for problems like yours: https://regex101.com/r/xM2aYZ/1

Comment: thanks for sharing a good link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
r'(?P<host>[\d.]+)\ -\ (?P<user_name>\w+)\ \[(?P<time>[^][]+)]\ "(?P<request>[^"]+)"'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HIFeZ9/2)

**Details**

- `(?P<host>[\d.]+)` - Group "host": one or more digits / dots
- `\ -\`  - a string
- `(?P<user_name>\w+)` - Group "user_name": one or more word chars
- `\ \[` - space + `[`
- `(?P<time>[^][]+)` - Group "time": one or more chars other than `]` and `[`
- `]\ "` - `] "` substring
- `(?P<request>[^"]+)` - Group "request": one or more chars other than a `"`
- `"`  - a `"` char.

Comment: r'(?P<host>[\d.]+)\ -\ (?P<user_name>\w+)\ \[(?P<time>[^][]+)]\ "(?P<request>[^"]+)"'

Comment: @KanikaSinghal Ok, you might not need the start of string check.